# How to convert this polynomial to partial fraction?

Tags: polynomials, partial-fractions

I want to convert this polynomoial to partial fraction.

$$
\frac{x^2-2x+2}{x(x-1)}
$$

I proceed like this:
$$
\frac{x^2-2x+2}{x(x-1)} = \frac{A}{x} + \frac{B}{x-1}
$$
Solving,
$$
A=-2,B=1
$$
But this does not make sense. What is going wrong?

Comment: That is not a polynomial but a rational function.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{x^2-2x+2}{x(x-1)}=1+\frac Ax+\frac B{x-1}$$

Now what you have to do to solve for A and B is to multiply both sides of your equation by $x(x-1)$, and that should give you something like.

$$\frac{x^2-2x+2}{1}=x^2-x +A(x-1)+Bx=x(A+B)-A=-x+2$$ From here on it's pretty easy to solve for both A and B.

Answer (score 0):

As the highest power of $x$ in the numerator & the denominator are same,

using [Partial Fraction Decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition),
$$\frac{x^2-2x+2}{x(x-1)}=1+\frac Ax+\frac B{x-1}$$

$1$ is found by $$\frac{\text{The coefficient of the highest power of }x\text{ in the numerator}}{\text{The coefficient of the highest power of }x\text{ in the denominator}}$$

Comment: Can you explain why $1$ comes? I didn't get that from your answer.

Comment: @gyeox29ns, Have you read the last line of the answer?

Comment: yes I did. But I didn't get that. Do you want to say that when powers of numerator and denominator are same, we introduce 1?

Comment: @gyeox29ns, Consequently yes

Answer (score 0):

An idea I didn't see in the other answers:

$$\frac{x^2-2x+2}{x(x-1)}=\frac{(x-1)^2+1}{x(x-1)}=\frac{x-1}x+\frac1{x(x-1)}=1-\frac1x+\frac1{x(x-1)}$$

And now either directly: $\;\frac1{x(x-1)}=\frac1{x-1}-\frac1x\;$ ,or by partial fractions, so that finally

$$\frac{x^2-2x+2}{x(x-1)}=1-\frac2x+\frac1{x-1}$$